# .NET Web API WebHook won't accept XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Via Postman I am receiving the the following response:

```
The WebHook request must contain an entity body formatted as JSON
```

With the help of some online tutorials I set up a webhook receiver that successfully reads in events from GitHub.

The next hurdle is being able to to receive a request containing XML data. I brought in the relevant `WebHooks.Custom` packages via NuGet so that I can handle a less specific request. I'm able to get into the `ExecuteAsync` method in my `CustomWebHookHandler` class and read in the data if it's sent as JSON, but if I change the raw body of the request to XML (along with the content-type in the header) I get the error listed above.

Do .NET Web API projects not handle XML out of the box? All commments I found elsewhere stated that they *do* handle XML.

If they don't handle XML out of the box how do I change the app to allow XML?
If they do handle XML out of the box why am I getting the error message above?